# Apply Binding to class - knockout js

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have on my page two div's(one at the top and one at the bottom) each containing links for pagination. I am using knockout to get the data when selected and doing ajax call to update the model and view which all works perfectly. As the top/bottom html is the same I want to use one model on the class div class - pagination. As I have discovered - You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element in knockout. Does anyone have an appropriate efficient method to use without duplication of code.

Thanks

Comment: you can have multiple bindings for different different elements but not for same element

Comment: I managed to sort it out straight after posting, by having different id for each.

Comment: @user2025749 probably best to delete the question if you've solved the issue